# (Resolved) Audio over bluetooth doesn't work when launch as a systemd service

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I'm running into a similar issue as ([Can't play audio via BT from systemd service](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/142502/cant-play-audio-via-bt-from-systemd-service/142525#142525?newreg=c8a7f0d265f947dc86ac424a21939637)) on my project where audio works fine in the python script if I launch it from the command line, but if I move it to a systemd service, then audio over bluetooth doesn't work. Audio does work using a headphone jack.

I did another experiment where I stopped the systemd service and manually launched the program and audio over bluetooth started working. When I looked at the output of "sudo systemctl status bluetooth" before and after running the program manually (after stopping the systemd service), I noticed the following:

Before:

```
Dec 30 23:17:26 raspberrypi bluetoothd[526]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.40 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
Dec 30 23:17:29 raspberrypi bluetoothd[526]: profiles/audio/avctp.c:avctp_control_confirm() Control: Refusing unexpected connect
```

After:

```
Dec 30 23:17:29 raspberrypi bluetoothd[526]: profiles/audio/avctp.c:avctp_control_confirm() Control: Refusing unexpected connect
Dec 30 23:31:21 raspberrypi bluetoothd[526]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_30_22_90_91_05_21/sep1/fd1: fd(29) ready
```

It looks like somehow bluez stuff starts working when I run the program manually.

Any idea what needs to be done to configure bluez (and necessary dependency) at the startup of Raspberry pi?

EDIT: I moved from systemd service to crontab and ran into the exact same issue there. After doing some research, I found the following post and that helped to resolve the issue I was facing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497130/audio-doesnt-play-with-crontab-on-raspberry-pi/43436895#43436895

Comment: :P  well, the obvious answer is, "Don't use `systemd`"  Have you tried starting this as a `cron` job?

Comment: No, I haven't tried a cron job option yet. Let me give it a shot. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just tried a cron job and saw the exact same issue as systemd. 

Could there be some permission issue where audio over bluetooth wouldn't play for the programs that are starting at startup (vs. manually running it from terminal)?

Comment: I also tried running the following speaker test in a cron job, but I don't hear anything on my bluetooth speaker when the job runs. However, if I run the following command from the shell manually, then I hear the test wav file fine on the bluetooth speaker. 


`speaker-test -t wav -c 2 -l 1`

Comment: In this test, I have the same observation as my original post when I run `sudo systemctl status bluetooth`. 

The following shows up when I run the command manually from the shell. 


Dec 31 10:43:36 raspberrypi bluetoothd[808]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_30_22_90_91_05_21/sep1/fd1: fd(29) ready

Comment: Edit your question to add the `cron` job - just as you entered it in `crontab`.       These comments get *messy*, and they are not intended to be used to provide details that could/should have been in the question. :)

Comment: Thanks to following post, I was able to resolve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497130/audio-doesnt-play-with-crontab-on-raspberry-pi/43436895#43436895

Comment: Congratulations!!  Suggestion:  Answer your own question. Paraphrase the answer from SO (in your own words), give credit to the SO answer (hyperlink), accept your answer (may have to wait a day or two). This will help other users here who are looking for **answers** (not comments).